# Explain the float - int problem in factorization

Tags: python, floating-point, int, factorization

I am missing here the technical word but the problem here is either to change int to float or float to int.

```
def factorize(n):
    def isPrime(n):
        return not [x for x in range(2,int(math.sqrt(n)))
                    if n%x == 0]
    primes = []
    candidates = range(2,n+1)
    candidate = 2
    while not primes and candidate in candidates:
        if n%candidate == 0 and isPrime(candidate):

            # WHY ERROR?
            #I have tried here to add float(), int() but cannot understand why it returns err
            primes = primes + [float(candidate)] + float(factorize(n/candidate))
        candidate += 1
    return primes
```

The err -- tried fixing it with functions such as `int()` and `float()` but still persist:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Why are floats involved in a `factorize` function at all?

Comment: dan04: just overuse, killed it. Now it works but still wondering about other problems, more succint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression is your immediate problem:

```
float(factorize(n/candidate))
```

`factorize` returns a list, but `float` needs its argument to be a string or a number.

(Your code has many, many other problems but perhaps it would be best for you to discover them for yourself...)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you return a `list` and in the line:

```
primes = primes + [float(candidate)] + float(factorize(n/candidate))
```

But `float` works on numbers or strings, not a list.

The correct solution would be:

```
primes = primes + [float(candidate)] + [float(x) for x in factorize(n/candidate)]
# Converting every element to a float
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot understand what Gareth meant with `many, many other problems`, the problem is in sanitization!

```
def factorize(n):
    # now I won`t get floats
    n=int(n)

    def isPrime(n):
        return not [x for x in range(2,int(math.sqrt(n)))
                    if n%x == 0]

    primes = []
    candidates = range(2,n+1)
    candidate = 2
    while not primes and candidate in candidates:
        if n%candidate == 0 and isPrime(candidate):
            primes = primes + [candidate] + factorize(n/candidate)
        candidate += 1
    return primes


clearString = sys.argv[1]
obfuscated = 34532.334
factorized = factorize(obfuscated)

print("#OUTPUT "+factorized)


#OUTPUT [2, 2, 89, 97]
```

**Better but can you do it simpler or fewer lines?**

```
def factorize(n):
    """ returns factors to n """

    while(1):
            if n == 1:
                    break

            c = 2 

            while n % c != 0:
                    c +=1

            yield c
            n /= c

 print([x for x in factorize(10003)])
```

**Time comparison**

```
$ time python3.1 sieve.py 
[100003]

real    0m0.086s
user    0m0.080s
sys 0m0.008s
$ time python3.1 bad.py 
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "obfuscate128.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(factorize(1000003))
  File "obfuscate128.py", line 19, in factorize
    if n%candidate == 0 and isPrime(candidate):
KeyboardInterrupt

real    8m24.323s
user    8m24.320s
sys 0m0.016s
```

The `at least O(n)` is a big understatement, lol what I can find from google, let's consider the poor result with large prime. `10003` pawns at least `10002!` subprocesses, `10003` pawns `10002` because each fail and it cannot be evaluated until each of their subprocesses are evaluated and each `n` subprocess will have `n-1` subprocesses. Good example how not to factorize.